# HOW to train and predict an ML model with Multiple time series data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I am collecting multivariate data hourly from multiple devices (time series). How can I train a model using this data and use the model to predict future data points?

I want the predictions to get better as I record more data from a device.

*This is not a multivariate problem, but Multi time series problem.*

*I want to use multiple time series with multivariables to predict multistep several times in to the recording*

Answer (score 0):

You can use LSTM, GRU, which are a variant of RNN. However, as you mention `multiple time series`, it seem to be needed to apply different strategy in order to do that.

I assume that the multiple time of your data is correlate. In this case, arrange all of the sample in chronological order, extract meaning other features from the dataset, and feed to the model.